# Python, Jenkins, Selenium Exception: Can't load the profile. Xlib: extension "RANDR" missing on display

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I am trying to do some continuous integration with Jenkins on an Amazon EC2 instance with an NGinX web server. When I go to build, the console output gives a long traceback for my selenium functional tests:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Todo-list/workspace/functional_tests/base.py", line 37, in setUp
    self.browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/b76d4922/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout),
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/b76d4922/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/b76d4922/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 61, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable()
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/b76d4922/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 105, in _wait_until_connectable
    self.profile.path, self._get_firefox_output()))
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'Can\'t load the profile. Profile Dir: /tmp/tmp6u1x3k5x Firefox output: b\'Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1013".\\n1431149116679\\taddons.manager\\tDEBUG\\tLoaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm: ...more error lines...
```

My code:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import sys
from .server_tools import reset_database
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
#from .server_tools import reset_database

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
display.start()
binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/local/firefox/firefox')
class FunctionalTest(StaticLiveServerTestCase):

[...]
    def setUp(self):

        if self.against_staging:
            reset_database(self.server_host)
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)
```

I've tried doing sudo Xvfb :1 -ac with my DISPLAY =:1 in my bash_profile but that doesn't seem to help. I've also tried pip install -U selenium. Any suggestions as to how to handle this error?

Comment: have you tried adding "-extension RANDR" to Xvfb command? depending how you use it it will be something like `Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1280x800x24 -extension RANDR &`

Comment: @Stanjer Yes I have tried that no luck

Comment: And you always get the same error?